# Gravity Forms - Get a Date value and adjust it, make it into a merge tag

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

So what I want to be able to do is take a field value, a date field, and add a set period of time to it and then make that into a merge tag that I can then add back into that value or use else where.

I know how to make a new merge tag, that's not the issue. My question is how do I get a field value to use in that calculation?

```
add_filter( 'gform_replace_merge_tags', 'new_date_plus_30', 10, 7 );
function new_date_plus_30( $text, $form, $entry, $url_encode, $esc_html, $nl2br, $format ) {
    $merge_tag = '{date_plus_30}';

    $new_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+30 days'));

    return str_replace( $merge_tag, $new_date, $text );
}
```

So where I do the new date calculation, I need to be able to pull in a field from that post and use it.

I was also thinking of doing a If / Else script where I would do the date calculation based on what was set in a form. So if a user said repeat this every 15 days, I would have something like:

add_filter( 'gform_replace_merge_tags', 'new_date_plus_30', 10, 7 );
function new_date_plus_30( $text, $form, $entry, $url_encode, $esc_html, $nl2br, $format ) {

```
if ( $form_id == 34 && $field_id == 2 && $value == 'add 30 days') {

$merge_tag = '{date_plus_30}';
$new_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+30 days'));

}
else if ( $form_id == 34 && $field_id == 2 && $value == 'first of month') {

  $merge_tag = '{first_of_month}';
  $new_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('first of next month'));

 }

}

return str_replace( $merge_tag, $new_date, $text );


}
```

But my issue is still the same. How can I use two filters at the same time? I assume I need to use the gform_get_input_value. Kindly review my code and give feedback is there other way?

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe something like this...

```
     add_filter( 'gform_merge_tag_filter', function ( $value, $merge_tag, $options, $field, $raw_value ) {
    if ( $field->id == '2' && $value == 'first of the month') {
       $merge_tag = '{the_next_date}';
       $thedatetochange = 'Not sure how to get the date value here...';
       $value = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($thedatetochange . 'first of the next month'));

       return $value;
    }
else if ( $field->id == '2' && $value == 'the 15th') {
       $merge_tag = '{the_next_date}';
       $thedatetochange = 'Not sure how to get the date value here...';
       $the_first_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($thedatetochange . 'first of the next month' ));
       $value = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($the_first_date . '+15 days' ));

       return $value;
    }
}, 10, 5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

So after doing more digging, would I be able to use something like this to get the value of the field?

```
$theDateToChange = rgar( $entry, ‘3’);
```

This assumes that the field 3 is a date value. Would this work for retrieving the current entry date?

Answer (score 0):

The `$entry` is passed through the gform_replace_merge_tags filter. You can fetch any field value from the `$entry` by its field ID. For example, if your field ID was 1:

```
$value = $entry[1];
```

Alternately, if you're open to capturing this modified date as a secondary Date field in your form, we have a snippet that can handle the functionality for you.

https://gravitywiz.com/populate-dates-gravity-form-fields/

```
new GW_Populate_Date( array(
 'form_id' => 1,
 'target_field_id' => 2,
 'modifier' => '+30 days'
) );
```

Comment: Hey David, I actually read that article several times to see if I could do something with mine. The issue I have with yours is I would need to add in if / else functionality. More or less I would need to create multiple GW_Populate_date arrays. Believe me I was very keen on doing it. But I need to be able to up date the date by 1 month, 3 months, 6 months and 1 year depending on the option that a user defines.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my current working code...

```
    add_action( 'gform_admin_pre_render', 'add_merge_tags' );
function add_merge_tags( $form ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        gform.addFilter('gform_merge_tags', 'add_merge_tags');
        function add_merge_tags(mergeTags, elementId, hideAllFields, excludeFieldTypes, isPrepop, option){
            mergeTags["custom"].tags.push({ tag: '{the_next_date}', label: 'The Next Date' });

            return mergeTags;
        }
    </script>
    <?php
    //return the form object from the php hook
    return $form;
}

add_action('wp', 'add_merge_tags');

/** MY MERGE TAGS HERE */

add_filter( 'gform_replace_merge_tags', 'new_date', 10, 7 ); 
function new_date( $value, $merge_tag, $options, $field, $raw_value, $entry, $text, $form, $url_encode, $esc_html, $nl2br, $format ) {

    $pmoptions = $entry[7];

if ( $pmoptions == 'Monthly') {

       $merge_tag = '{the_next_date}';
       $old_date = $entry[2];
       $new_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime( $old_date . '+1 month'));

       return str_replace( $merge_tag, $new_date, $text );
    }
else if ( $pmoptions == 'Quarterly') {

       $merge_tag = '{the_next_date}';
       $old_date = $entry[2];
       $new_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime( $old_date . '+3 month'));

       return str_replace($merge_tag, $new_date, $text);
    }
}

apply_filters( 'gform_replace_merge_tags', $value, $merge_tag, $options, $field, $raw_value, $entry, $text, $form, $url_encode, $esc_html, $nl2br, $format );
```